# Search through an array and test for equality

Tags: ruby, arrays

I have two classes: `Item` and `ItemCollection`. `Item` has several attributes: `attr1`, `attr2`, `attr3`, etc., and `ItemCollection` holds an array of `Item` instances, along with some manipulating methods.

Question 1: is this the appropriate way to handle a collection of objects?

I want a method: `ItemCollection#itemExists(needleItem)`, which returns `true` if `needleItem.attr1 == attr1` for some item within the array of the `ItemCollection` instance.

Question 2: What is the best way to do this?

Comment: What does ItemCollection’s code look like? Specifically, what is the internal data structure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you could do count. http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-count

simple code for this would be:

```
def check_needle
  c = ItemCollection.count { |i|
      needleitem.attr1 == i.attr1 # Each time this value returns true it enumerates
  }

  c > 1
  # or 
  if c > 1 then return true end
end
```

I suppose needleitem is in the array ? If so any count greater than 1 for c should be fine. If not, any count greater than 0 for c should satisfy. Plus you get the total count.

-Douglas

Comment: Also it depends why you want to know this. If you are trying to work with an array that only has Items where attr1 matching you can do ItemCollection.keepif instead of count. If you want to do those that don't, do .deleteif. http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-keep_if OR http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-delete_if   Then c would be the resultant array.

Comment: If you use `count`, you will always have to loop through the entire collection to do the test, even if the first element matches.

Comment: True, it all comes down to WHY you want to know.

Answer (score 1):

> Question 1: is this the appropriate way to handle a collection of objects?

You can derive your `ItemCollection` class from `Array` and get its methods for free.

> Question 2: what is the best way to do this?

I see two options (assuming you're following my previous advice):

1. Override `include?` method in `ItemCollection` using simple iteration with `each`:

   ```
   class ItemCollection < Array
     def include?(item)
       self.each do |i|
         return true if i.attr1 == item.attr1
       end
       return false
     end
   end
   ```
2. Provide your own equality test for `Item` instances and use default `include?` version derived from `Array` (`Item`s with equal `attr1` will always be considered equal):

   ```
   class Item
     def initialize(attr1, attr2, attr3)
       @attr1, @attr2, @attr3 = attr1, attr2, attr3
     end

     attr_accessor :attr1, :attr2, :attr3

     def ==(another)
       self.attr1 == another.attr1
     end
   end
   ```

Answer (score 1):

If ItemCollection only holds the array and a few methods (and no other related data) -- then there is really no need for that extra class. Just use an array and define the methods as simple functions.

As for searching the array -- Douglas answer is probably best. However, another method (probably less efficient) would be to use `Array#map` to extract `attr1` from the objects in the array and then `array#include?` to search for the desired value. E.g.

```
 collectionArray.map(&:attr1).include?(attr_to_find)
```

The `&:attr1` syntax is equivalent to 
     { |x| x.attr1 }

and is used to map the objects array into an array containing only the desired attributes.

Comment: Same problem as with Douglas' solution: you always have to go though the entire collection to check if an item is in the collection.

Comment: @nameless: Good point. Added my vote to your answer. The real answer is to use a better data structure and avoid the O(n) search altogether.

Answer (score 0):

A ruby array instance has more then 100 methods, excluding those of Object. Many of them are very flexible. The `any?` method (included from [enumerable](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerable.html)) takes a block, allowing you to specify the condition when it should return true.

```
class Item < Struct.new(:attr1, :attr2)
end
p item_collection = Array.new(10){|n| Item.new(rand(10), n)}
#[#<struct Item attr1=7, attr2=0>, #<struct Item attr1=5, attr2=1>,
#<struct Item attr1=8, attr2=2>, #<struct Item attr1=3, attr2=3>, 
#<struct Item attr1=9, attr2=4>, #<struct Item attr1=8, attr2=5>, 
#<struct Item attr1=1, attr2=6>, #<struct Item attr1=6, attr2=7>, 
#<struct Item attr1=4, attr2=8>, #<struct Item attr1=6, attr2=9>]

p item_collection.any?{|i| i.attr1 == 3}
#true
```

When item_collection should have a very special method, then a possibility is to define it on the item_collection array:

```
def item_collection.very_special_method
  self.select{|i| i.attr1 == i.attr2}
end
p item_collection.very_special_method
# [#<struct Item attr1=3, attr2=3>]
```